# Vba making mulitstate symbols disappear

Tags: vba

I am using VBA for processbook. I am trying to get the multistate values for a symbol and make it only visible if it is on or in state 2. It is not working and cant figure out what else I need to include in my code. It is giving me an error saying "Object variable or with block variable not set" Any thoughts?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Display_DataUpdate()
Dim Simplehorizontalconveyor_16 As Symbol
Dim curState16 As MultiState

    Set curState16 = Simplehorizontalconveyor_16.GetMultiState
        If (curState16 = 2) Then
            Simplehorizontalconveyor_16.Visible = True
        Else
            Simplehorizontalconveyor_16.Visible = False
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of Simplehorizontalconveyor_16:

```
Set Simplehorizontalconveyor_16 = <something>
```